# Will images, saved within the app be deleted after updating app from the App Store?

Tags: ios

I am writing some images within my app using this

```
  func saveImageLocally(imageData:NSData!) -> String{
    let time =  NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("userContactImages") as String
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dir) {
        var error: NSError?
        if !fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error) {
            println("Unable to create directory: \(error)")
            return ""
        }
    }

    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("spot\(Int(time)).png")
    var error: NSError?
    if !imageData.writeToFile(path, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic, error: &error) {
        println("error writing file: \(error)")
        return ""
    }
    return path
}
```

And I am loading files like this:

```
func loadImageFromLocalStore(path: String) -> UIImage{
    if(path.isEmpty || UIImage(named: path) == nil){
        return UIImage(named: "noImage.png")!
    }else{
        return UIImage(named: path)!
    }
}
```

Now I have submitted my app to the app store successfully. One of my friends had a dev version of my app installed before loading the app from the App Store. He saved a few images, but after the update, all the images are gone.
I see the same while developing, each time I deploy a new version to my phone, the images are gone.

Now my question. Will the images be deleted each time, the user updates my app, or is this behavior "just because" it was a development version and not actually a version from the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppStore version is possibly using a different development profile to build the app (AppStore Distribution profile), so it will be another app besides your app using your for development. So is the data.

The code looks good, the data will stay there if you will update the app again in AppStore.